# Cannot load scripts in html

Tags: html, windows

I've got kind of a weird problem going on: If want to load anything ("local scripts, css) within my html it just can't find the file. I'm using a relative path

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

And yes the path is absolutely right. I think the problem is my pc itself. If i pass in the exact path in my hdd it's able to get the file. So I assume that means that my browser or html file cannot access the files? Also if I look at the folders options it says that the folder is read-only and if I uncheck that everything works for 30 secs and after that I have got the same problem...

Comment: Does this work? <script src="~/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

Comment: is the path relative to the site root? remove the first slash and check what happens.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but are you opening the web page from the file system or from a web server?  If the file system then this path won't work.  That root path indicator is relative to the web server.

Comment: It's on my own pc and no it does not change anything if i remove the "/"

Comment: Then it doesn't on a local Web Server? what is the address of the page?

Comment: @fxcutz: "My own PC" doesn't really answer the question.  *How* are you opening the web page?  Are you opening it from a URL to a web server (such as `http://localhost`), or are you opening it as an actual file from the file system?  Again, to the file system that path likely wouldn't make much sense.  You'd need to specify the path relative to the file being opened, not relative to the root of the site (since there *is no* site when opening from the file system).

Comment: I've tried to open the html file as a file in chrome and I tried it using a simple express server

Comment: Just type the address of your page here.I think you don't run it on a local server, it should starts with http://

Comment: it's a local server.

Comment: @fxcutz: Can you provide more information?  "yes the path is absolutely right" isn't really helpful.  What is the address of the page you're viewing?  What is its location on the file system?  What is the location of the `.js` file on the file system?  Can you manually open the `.js` file in the browser from its web address?  What address is it located at?

Comment: page: C:/Projects/stundenplan/puplic/index.html js: C:/Projects/stundenplan/puplic/bower_components/angular/angular.js (none of my js files are loading) If use the dev tools and look at the resources of my page, chrome is looking for the files at file:///C:/bower_components/angular/angular.js

Comment: "on my hdd"? YOu're loading this `file:///` urls? Then your `/bower` path is going to be absolute relative to the drive the container page was loaded from.

Comment: no, i do have other projects in which im doing the exact same thing and its working

Answer (score 2):

According to comments posted on the question...

Your "web page" is here:

```
C:/Projects/stundenplan/puplic/index.html
```

This isn't coming from a web server, it's coming from the file system.  So this path:

```
/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

is relative to the root of *the file system*, not the web server.  Which means it translates to this:

```
C:/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

According to you, the `.js` file is located here:

```
C:/Projects/stundenplan/puplic/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

Those are different paths, so naturally the browser isn't loading the file.  You'd need to change the path from root-relative to page-relative, such as this:

```
./bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

Or perhaps this:

```
bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

Or, if you want it to be root-relative, it would need the whole path from root:

```
/Projects/stundenplan/puplic/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

The **main point** here, however, is that file systems make for terrible web servers.  So you're going to run into further problems like this one.  If you want this to be a web page, make it a web page.  That is, something opened from a web server.  There are many personal web servers available.  In fact, I think every major operating system today comes with one built in.  IIS, Apache, etc.

With a web server set up, you would have a *site root* for the website.  So when you open your page here:

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

Then this path:

```
/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

would translate to:

```
http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

Which is a valid path to the `.js` file.

Comment: @fxcutz: I think you're getting confused between file systems and web servers.  And that confusion is bringing misinformation to your question.  If you could elaborate in the question itself with more information, that might help.  But so far all you want us to do is take your word for it that everything is set up right and somehow not working.  We can't help with that.

Comment: I think its better we both vote up each other after the efforts!

Comment: @fxcutz: It's not a waste of time at all, we're all here to help.  If you've been able to solve the issue then mission accomplished :)

Answer (score 1):

As you don't run it on a server (local or remote) you either must insert the absolute path or a path relative to the file you have opened.

You may need to setup a local Web server like [Apache](http://apache.org/) or IIS if you want to develop a website.

For [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/), check [this page](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html) which guides you how to run your app

Comment: I'm using node.js with express.js as my local server. And yes I'm using a correct relative path, just look at the other comments.

Comment: if you have a local web server, it must begins with `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` and not `file:///` and if you don't have a server you should use the relative path to your file. check in the browser if you have a local server by typing the address I gave you.

Comment: Yes localhost is working. The file:/// path is coming from the dev tools: the are displaying the exact path chrome is looking for the file and because the server is local chrome is looking for the file on my pc

Comment: if localhost is working you should find the folder which is your document root, or www. Does localhost shows any folder? if you copy your file in the  root folder of localhost and use a path relative to your website root (probably without first slash) it may works

Comment: Thats not working because with expressjs you have to define every route

Comment: check this page, and use how it runs a page http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: @fxcutz if you find my guides helpful, accept it as answer by checking the tick near the answer.

Comment: But they are not helpful

Comment: @fxcutz You need to edit your question and ask it about expressjs routing and also if you want to run it on localhost or just as a file on system.